# Browse button not in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to implement a browse button which would not be in a form tag in MVC?
I want a normal button - when clicked, to handle the file selected.

Comment: How do you want to handle the file?

Comment: @SLaks Just get its location.

Comment: For security reasons, that's totally impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible to do. The browse button has to be in a form tag.